# syncing php.ini CentOS 9

Tags: php, centos

PHP 8.3.2 (cli) - CentOS 9
This is a new machine that I need to update for WordPress and MediaWiki - update scripts are failing with errors for missing php extensions (mbstring, mysqli, intl).

webserver phpinfo display shows these installed and enabled.

"php -m" they aren't there.

php --ini showed no config files initially, so I linked /etc/php.ini to /usr/local/lib, but this isn't picking up the additional .ini files in /etc/php.d

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

How can I configure things to scan the php.d directory of .ini files from the command line and get these missing extensions included?

---

PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php.d php -m

This got the *.ini files for modules included, however the modules then couldn't be found.

I gave up and reverted back to PHP 8.0

Comment: PHP extensions are typically installed/removed using binary packages (in CentOS, it should be *.rpm packages using yum, if I recall correctly).

Comment: Thanks Alvaro - yum now updated to dnf - remove/install for the extensions seemed not to change the command line php setup.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. As you can see in [package list](https://mirror.stream.centos.org/9-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/), you need to install the appropriate package for each extension you want to use, e.g. `php-mbstring`, and package scripts will take care of adding the appropriate INI settings.